# Android - HttpClient.execute(HttpPost) randomly throws IOException (Connection refused)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, androidhttpclient

I have created a class to handle API request by extended from `AsyncTask<String,String,byte[]>`. Randomly the part `response = client.execute(post);` throwing IO error with the message `Connection to [URL] refused`

```
@Override protected byte[] doInBackground(String... uri) {
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> list = this.params==null?null:new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(this.params.size());
    byte[] result = null;
    HashMap<String,Object> iterated = this.params==null?null:(HashMap<String, Object>) this.params.clone();
    if(iterated!=null&&iterated.size()!=0) try{
        Iterator iterator = iterated.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
            String key = String.valueOf(pair.getKey());
            String val = String.valueOf(pair.getValue());
            if(list!=null) list.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key,val));
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException ex){
        return null;
    }
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(this.url);
    try{
        if(list!=null) post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list));
    }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException ex){
        return null;
    }
    if(isCancelled()||post.isAborted()) return null;
    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, this.timeout);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
    HttpResponse response;
    try{
        response = client.execute(post);
    }catch(ClientProtocolException ex){
        return null;
    }catch(IOException ex) {
        return null;
    }
    StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();
    if(isCancelled()||post.isAborted()) return null;
    if(status.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) try{
        if(response.getEntity()==null) return null;
        Header responsetype = response.getEntity().getContentType();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
        result = out.toByteArray();
    }catch(IOException ex){}
    else response.getEntity().getContent().close();
    return result;
}
```

These are some logged texts

```
06-24 16:08:25.825: I/System.out(12858): Url : http://www.x.com/api/index.php/notification/listNotification
06-24 16:08:25.825: I/System.out(12858): Parameters : {loginkey=sa119k338r4chtr3}
06-24 16:08:28.855: I/System.out(12858): IOException : Connection to http://www.x.com refused
```

Comment: check your url in web, will it working good??? because connection refused cause only in the case of url problem

Comment: which url did you mean? the url and parameters is always correct. i try to put some headers for example content type but with no luck

Comment: did you got values with your webservice ??

Comment: did u mean that did i received the result from the api? nope

Comment: yeah, what response you got from api ???

Comment: i believe the client.execute(post) will always return null if there's an error, if that's the response you meant

Comment: That's a pretty specific error message.  What makes you think it isn't actually a refused connection at the server side?

Comment: @DavidSainty Because it's random. I've also tried using a rest api http client app without getting any such errors

Comment: I would look at the network and see what was happening there.  You'll immediately be able to see whether the refused connection is real or not.  Ideally you should watch from the client side - best case use tcpdump on a rooted phone, or perhaps from your WiFi access point.  Second best would be from the server if you have access, using tcpdump or wireshark.